# dompdf - set page margin only after first page

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I am converting an `HTML` to `pdf` file using `dompdf`. It is working fine. But the problem is that I need to have page margin for all the pages **except** the first page. The first page should have an image covering the whole page. But now the margin is coming for all pages including the first one.

I am not able to disable margin for the first page. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is my css

```
  <style type="text/css">
    body { margin: 0px; }
    @page { margin: 50px; }
    #header { 
      position: fixed; 
      left: 0px; 
      top: -52px;
      height: 50px; 
      border-bottom: 2px solid #797979;
      margin: 0; 
    }
    #footer { 
      position: fixed; 
      left: 0px; 
      bottom: -52px;
      height: 50px; 
      border-top: 2px solid #797979;
      margin: 0; 
    }
    #footer .page:after { content: counter(page); }
    .firstpage { 
      position: absolute;
      page-break-after: always; 
      top: -50px;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .otherpages{ margin: 0; }
  </style>
```

And here's my html

```
  <div class="firstpage">
     <img src="pdf-bg.jpg" style="width:100%; height:auto;/>
  </div>

  <div id="header">
    <p><?php echo date("F j, Y"); ?></p>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p class="page">Page <?php $PAGE_NUM ?></p>
  </div>    

  <div class="otherpages">
      some content
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
    @page { margin: 50px 0; }
    .firstpage { 
      position: absolute;
      page-break-after: always; 
      top: -50px; // compensating for @page top margin
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .otherpages{ margin: 0 50px; }
```